# Table position in JAVA

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Is there any method in java that lets me place a table in the center of the panel...

This is the code:

```
if(entp.isSelected() ){
    students = new DefaultTableModel();
    table.setVisible(true);
    table1.setVisible(false);
    table2.setVisible(false);
    table3.setVisible(false);
    table4.setVisible(false);
    ...
}
```

I'm importing this libraries:

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

and I need to place the called table,,,so table in this case in the center of the panel..

Help me plz:(

Comment: @cajunluke has pretty much explained centering below. But your question sounds vague and incomplete. If @cajunluke's answer did not work for you, please consider posting more details.

Comment: -1, you posted a question earlier on the same topic.

Answer (score 3):

Look up Layout Managers, specifically BorderLayout.

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
JTable table = new JTable(tableModel);
panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The table `table` is centered in `panel`.

(I'm assuming you're using Swing. If not, add your UI library as a tag and mention it in your post.)

Comment: pane1.add( new JScrollPane(table),BorderLayout.CENTER);
table.setVisible(false);    How can I change it?

Comment: I put the libraries in my post

Comment: You should remove the `setVisible(false);` it's making your table invisible.